# Manage docker containers in a college lab environment

Tags: docker, system-administration

Is there's a proper way to manage and configure docker containers in a college lab environment?

I requested for docker to be installed so that I could experiment with it for a project, but after speaking with our sysadmin, it seems very complicated. Wondering if SO has any insight.

Some exceptions that need to be handled:

- Students will download images, which may be bad
- Students may leave images running indefinitely
- Some containers will require elevated privileges, for networking/IO/et cetera
- Students will make images so images may be buggy, if docker is given a sticky permission bit or an elevated user group this may lead to a breach

One of the solutions that comes to mind is to just allow students to use a hypervisor within which they can install whatever software they like, including docker (we currently cannot do so), but that kinda bypasses the advantage of lightweight containers.

Comment: Since directly running Docker containers requires (or implies) root privilege, it’s not something you want to allow on shared hardware with untrusted users.  This isn’t really a programming question, though, so it seems a little off-topic for SO.

Comment: Noted. @DavidMaze for the future, what stackexchange forum do you recommend to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sysdmins' concerns are reasonable but using Docker should add only minor refinements to your existing security practices.

If your students have internet access today from these machines, then they can:

- download binaries that may be bad
- leave processes running indefinitely
- may require processes with elevated privileges
- may create buggy|insecure binaries

Containers provide some partitioning between processes on a machine but essentially all that happens is that namespaces are created and linux processes run in them; the name "containers" is slightly misleading, `ps aux` will show you **all** the processes (including container-based processes) running for the user on the machine.

So... Assuming you still need to control what students are downloading from the Internet and what roles they have on the machines:

- private Image registries may be used either from the Cloud or locally
- Registries can be coupled with vulnerability tools to help identify bad images
- Tidying students' "sessions" will cover the processes in Docker containers too
- Privilege escalations aren't complex (different but not complex)
- Using some form of VM virtualization on bare metal machine is a good idea
- If you were use Cloud-based VMs (or Containers), you can destroy these easily

One area where I find Docker burdensome is in managing the container life-cycle (`rm` old containers, tidying up images) but this should be manageable.